# Restructing app into server-side & client-side containers

Tags: node.js, express

What I'm trying to achieve is splitting up app.js in separate pieces. That's so far successful. My structure looks like this so far:

```
package.json
app.js
app/
  - server/
     - views/
     - router.js
  - public/
      - css/
      - images/
      - js/
      - robots.txt
```

Sounds good? Inside my app.js I have the following code:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("app:" + app.get('port') + " running through express server.");
})
```

I feel that my http:createServer is so little and so vulnerable that I want to extend it. Is there a way to put it inside `./app/server/http.js` and include the toobusy module (that, with the examples seems too hard for me).

Is there a solution?

Comment: It would be very beneficial if you could put a bit more description about your concerns of `http:createServer` being _so little and so vulnerable_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is create a `app/server/http.js` file and place this code inside:

```
var toobusy = require('toobusy'),
    app = require('../../app');

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function () { ... });

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  server.close();
  // calling .shutdown allows your process to exit normally
  toobusy.shutdown();
  process.exit();
});
```

Then you can do one of two things:

1) Inside your `package.json` file, set the `main` field to `app/server/http.js` and you can start your app with `npm start` if thats your thing.

2) The other option (preferred, IMO) is to create an `index.js` file in the root of your project that looks something like:

```
module.exports = require('app/server/http');
```

And then you can simply start your server with

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node /path/to/project <arguments go here>
```

Either way, you'll get the benefits of `toobusy` while achieving the separation you desire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot in understanding the benefits while achieving the separation. +1

Comment: @RicardoJ One day you might consider splitting your server side and client side into two separate projects. This all depends on how much code you share between the two.